# Next.js 14 with Mobx

Tags: next.js, mobx

How do I integrate the Next.js 14 app router with Next.js? I have integrated the Next.js 14 app router with MobX, but the UI does not update when I update the store data. Before this, I was getting an 'undefined' error. To resolve this, I changed the function to an arrow function and it solved the problem. However, the UI is still not updating. I have also added the observer from the MobX-React package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out how to integrate Mobx with Next.js 14

```js
//store
export class UiStore {
  count = 0;
  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  increment = () => {
    this.count++;
  };
}


//group all store 
export const RootStore = {
  uiStore,
};


//provider

"use client";
import React, { createContext, ReactNode } from "react";
import { RootStore } from "@/store/store";

export const StoreContext = createContext(RootStore);

export const StoreWrapper = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={RootStore}>{children}</StoreContext.Provider>
  );
};


//main layout
  <StoreWrapper>{children}</StoreWrapper>


//hook to get stores

import { useContext } from "react";
import { StoreContext } from "@/store/provider";

export const useStores = () => {
  return useContext(StoreContext);
};


//component where you want to use store

"use client";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
import { useStores } from "@/hooks/useStore";

const HomePage = observer(() => {
  const {
    uiStore: { count, increment },
  } = useStores();

  return (
    <>
      <div>{count}</div>
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>)
    </>
  );
});

export default HomePage;
```